# All possible results from RESULT_SCAN known in advance?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

***(A Snowflake user brought this to my attention... Any recommendations?)***

---

After a merge statement, the "result set" can have 1, 2, or 3 columns returned depending on the potential of the merge.

For example,

> MERGE ... WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE ... will produce only "number of
>   rows updated"
>
> MERGE ... WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE ... WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
>   ... will produce both "number of rows updated" and "number of rows
>   inserted"
>
> MERGE...WHEN MATCHED ... THEN DELETE will also show "number of rows
>   deleted"

This means that RESULT_SCAN can return different columns depending on the capability of the merge.

Is there a reason why MERGE cannot return all three columns regardless? Afterall, even a simple "`UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = 5`" will return both "number of rows updated" and "number of multi-joined rows updated" even though the capability of the statement would never produce the latter.

Further, is there a list anywhere in Snowflake documentation that shows all the possible columns in the result set for any given operation? I know I could "DESCRIBE RESULT(QueryID)" in order to get the list of column names, but this is added work I was hoping to avoid.

*We received this forum response to our original question:*

> When you are using the result_scan method, are you using the specific
>   id? If you would like to show all three columns regardless, you may
>   want to consider using
>
> `desc result last_query_id();`
>
> `select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));`
>
> reference:  https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html
>
> **...shows all the possible columns in the result set for any given
>   operation?**
>
> Are you in the UI, you will be able to see the column names in the
>   Object Browser:
>   https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/snowflake-manager.html#worksheet-page

HOWEVER:

If the MERGE doesn't have a path that uses INSERT, then the result set / RESULT_SCAN does not return a "number of rows inserted" column. To me that's a problem. Likewise for paths to an UPDATE or DELETE.

I know how to get all columns for a table. My question is how to get all columns for a given query via RESULT_SCAN. Since it is dynamic and depends on the query id, can you please list all possible columns from a INSERT statement, a MERGE statement, a DESCRIBE statement, etc... ?

Comment: This comes with both disadvantages (more work in exception handling) and advantages (knowing that absence of a "deleted" result set colum means there is no DELETE branch in the MERGE).  So your mileage may vary.

Comment: The point about `UPDATE` not providing the capability of multi-joined rows being updated is **incorrect**. This happens when there is a non-deterministic join. You may have the option [ERROR_ON_NON_DETERMINISTIC_UPDATE](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#label-error-on-nondeterministic-update) set to `TRUE`.